# Django1.3 multiple gunicorn workers caching problems

Tags: caching, django-1.3, gunicorn

i have weird caching problems with the 1.3 version of django. I probably have something configured wrong, but am not sure what.

A good example is django-avatar, which uses caching and many people use it. Even if I dont have a cache backend defined the avatar seems to be cached, which by itself would be ok, but it keeps switching back and forth between the last values cached. Example: I upload a new avatar, now on approximately 50% of the requests it will show me the new one, 50% the old one. If I delete the old one I still get it on the site 50% of the time. The only way to fix it is to disable the caching of the avatar by setting it to one second.

First I thought it was because i used django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache, which I never used before, but it even happens when I dont configure a cache backend at all.

I found one similar bug: 
[Django caching bug .. even if caching is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888470/django-caching-bug-even-if-caching-is-disabled)

but my pages render just fine, its the templatetags (for now) that cause the problems in my setup.

I use django 1.3, postgres, nginx, gunicorn 0.12.0, greenlet==0.3.1, eventlet==0.9.16

I just did some more testing and realized that it only happens when I start gunicorn using the config file. If I start it with ./manage.py run_gunicorn everything is fine. Running "gunicorn_django -c deploy/gunicorn.conf.py" causes the problems.

The only explanation I can think of is that each worker gets his own cache (I wonder why, since I did not define a cache).

Update: running ./manage.py run_gunicorn -w 4 also causes the same problems. Therefore I am almost certain that the multiple workers are causing the problems and each worker caches the values seperately.

My configuration:

```
import os
import socket
import sys

PORT = 8000
PROC_NAME = 'myapp_gunicorn'
LOGFILE_NAME = 'gunicorn.log'
TIMEOUT = 3600
IP = '127.0.0.1'
DEPLOYMENT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
SITE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.sep.join([DEPLOYMENT_ROOT, '..']))
CPU_CORES = os.sysconf("SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, "apps"))
bind = '%s:%s' % (IP, PORT)
logfile = os.path.sep.join([DEPLOYMENT_ROOT, 'logs', LOGFILE_NAME])
proc_name = PROC_NAME
timeout = TIMEOUT
worker_class = 'eventlet'
workers = 2 * CPU_CORES + 1
```

---

I also tried it without using 'eventlet', but got the same errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: switching to memcache as caching backend solved my problem. however, I am still interested why this is happening...if i am doing something wrong or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is most likely defaulting to the in-memory-cache, which means each worker has it's own version of the cache in it's own memory space. If you hit thread 1 you get a different cache then thread 3. Nginx is spreading the load between each thread most likely via a round robin distribution, so you are changing threads each hit. Which explains your wacky results.

When you do manage.py run_gunicorn it is most likely running single threaded, and thus only one cache, and that is why you don't see the same results.

Using memcached or something similar is the way to go.

Comment: ok, kind of what i expected. it must have changed in the last version of django...since it worked before. it would probably be good to point that out in the documentation.

Comment: yes, very clear. nginx+gunicorn, recommend using `memcached` as cache.